# @JsonView is not working with inheritance

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller, json-view

I'm using **@JsonView** on simple classes (without inheritance) and it works fine.

But I have another case : **class B, C, D inheriting A and Class A inherits T.**
I put the **@JsonView** in th right get methods, but the filter is not working I always get all attributes in Json Body response.

Should I add a specific configuration in inheritance case?

***I used the following tutorial :***

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Ps:
I have added the @JsonView on the controller method also.
**@JsonView(DeliveryPrdViews.History.class)**

Did I miss anything?

Kr,